# How secure is Facebook's custom search?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-privacy

If I share a photo album on Facebook with "custom audience" then will their mutual friends will be able to see those photos?

I want to upload family albums and I want only selected people to see.

If a person in my custom audience comments on a post, can their friends (or our mutual friends) then see the post? (People who aren't in the custom audience.)

Answer (score 5):

No, other people will not be able to see that post.

From [What does the "Custom" privacy setting mean?](https://www.facebook.com/help/124768544269860/?q=privacy&sid=0RQN6eg0X7EVDgtyK):

> When you choose the Custom option in your [audience selector](https://www.facebook.com/help/120939471321735), you can share something with specific people, or hide it from specific people. You can also choose to share or hide posts from [friend lists](https://www.facebook.com/help/200538509990389) if you’ve set them up. Custom also gives you the option to share with groups or networks you belong to.

See this for more details: [What audiences can I choose from when I share?](https://www.facebook.com/help/211513702214269)